# Mapbox sdk blue dot not removing after navigation

Tags: android, navigation, mapbox, turn-by-turn

I am calling this on stop

navigation.endNavigation();
 locationLayerPlugin.onStop();             locationLayerPlugin.setLocationLayerEnabled(LocationLayerMode.COMPASS);
navigationMapRoute.removeRoute();

but blue dot is not removed from map

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling onstop and than enabling the location layer in that order, the location icon (blue dot) will show back up on the map? Could you explain a bit more what you are trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer after roaming in library code
need to use  NONE for plugin so blue dot was removed.